# A preprocessor #define to check for language version? C++98/C++03/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a preprocessor definition which I could use in `#ifdef` checks to discern the different versions of C++ language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of the `__cplusplus` macro is supposed to serve this purpose. Unfortunately, GCC has (before 4.7) always set this to `1`, making it unusable for this purpose.

(The values are `199711L` for C++98/03, and `201103L` for C++11.)

Comment: There is also the problem that the macro is set inconsistently. What should the value be for a compiler that supports parts of C++11? :/

Comment: @Xeo: `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` for clang and gcc.

Comment: @KennyTM: with libstdc++. In clang with `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` isn't defined. its also supposed to be removed when c++11 isn't experimental anymore